# Not able to perform operations on resulting dataframe after "join" operation in PySpark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, data-profiling

```
df=spark.read.csv('data.csv',header=True,inferSchema=True)
rule_df=spark.read.csv('job_rules.csv',header=True)
query_df=spark.read.csv('rules.csv',header=True)

join_df=rule_df.join(query_df,rule_df.Rule==query_df.Rule,"inner").drop(rule_df.Rule).show()
print(join_df.collect().columns)
```

Here I have created three dataframes: df,rule_df and query_df. I've performed inner join on rule_df and query_df, and stored the resulting dataframe in join_df. However, when I try to simply print the columns of the join_df dataframe, I get the following error-

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

The resultant dataframe is not behaving as one, I'm not able to perform any dataframe operations on it.

I'm guessing this error occurs when you're trying to call an object that doesn't exist, but it shouldn't be the case here as I'm able to view the resultant join_df.

Do I need to perform a different join in order to avoid this error? Might be a silly mistake, but I'm stumped trying to figure out what it is. Please help!

Comment: `.collect()` does not return a dataframe. you want `join_df.columns`. You'd also have to remove the `.show()` from the join line as it returns `None` and prints a sample. you need `join_df.show()` after the join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing several mistakes.

First of all you try to assign the return value of `.show()` to `join_df` which returns `None`.

Then you are calling the `.collect()` function which returns a list that contains all of the elements in this RDD. You need to call `.columns` directly on the `DataFrame`.

This should work:

```
join_df = rule_df.join(query_df,rule_df.Rule==query_df.Rule,"inner").drop(rule_df.Rule)
print(join_df.columns)
```

Comment: Rightt. Just saw this mistake. Really helpful, thank you so much!

Comment: Accepting / Upvoting the answer would be appreciated :)